# Linear separability in a 2×2×2 cube

Tags: analytic-geometry

Essentially, linearly separable points are just those corners that can be cut off with just one slice as marked out by a hyperplane. Can someone please explain how many cases there are for a $2\times2\times2$ cube?

The number of linearly separable cases are more in a $2\times2\times2$ than a $1\times1\times1$ cube.

I'm not sure how to calculate the number of possible cases for a $2\times2\times2$ cube. The case below is just one of many, and I would very much appreciate help with this.

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Bottom left is an example of a linearly separable case.
Bottom right is not linearly separable.

Comment: What's the difference between a $2\times2\times2$ cube and a $100\times100\times100$ cube? They both have 8 corners, and any way to slice off corners of one cube can be scaled to slice off the corresponding corners of the other.

Comment: Question unclear, and OP not responsive. Voting to close.

Comment: Still no explanation as to how the corners of a $2\times2\times2$ cube are any different from the corners of a $1\times1\times1$ cube.